# UIPageControl loading new view or different controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipagecontrol

I have just "attempted" to go over apples tutorial of PageControl. Now I should point out that I did not fully understand this, it seemed complex so I apologize if this question is very obvious.

I noticed that apple loaded its content from a .plist. Now thats all nice and easy if all you have is one UILabel and an UIImageView but what if I wana do something more complex? What if I want to each "page" to have like 14 different variables, a button on each "page" that does something else depending on what page you are...

So my question is this (perhaps this would not be smart to do in the first place):
Is there someway to code it so when the page is switched by the user, it loads a different controller that happens to have its own .Xib file and view already created in interface builder?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You would use a `UIPageViewController`. The `UIPageViewController` has data source and delegate methods that get called depending on whether the user swipes to the left or to the right. It basically says "Hey, give me the UIViewController that I should display before or after this UIViewController."

Here's a sample:

**MyPageViewController.h**:

```
@interface MyPageViewController : UIPageViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**MyPageViewController.m**:

```
#import "MyPageViewController.h"

@implementation MyPageViewController 

- (id)init
{
    self = [self initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                   navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                 options:nil];

    if (self) {
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.title = @"Some title";

        // set the initial view controller
        [self setViewControllers:@[[[SomeViewController alloc] init]]
                       direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                        animated:NO
                      completion:NULL];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewController DataSource methods
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    // here you put some logic to determine which view controller to return.
    // You either init the view controller here or return one that you are holding on to
    // in a variable or array or something.
    // When you are "at the end", return nil

    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    // here you put some logic to determine which view controller to return.
    // You either init the view controller here or return one that you are holding on to
    // in a variable or array or something.
    // When you are "at the end", return nil

    return nil;
}

@end
```

That's it!